# How do I open an .eml file from <botocore.response.StreamingBody> object using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am writing a Lambda function to read an email from a .eml file when the .eml file is stored in the S3 Bucket.

```
import email
.
.
.

# get the .eml file object from S3 bucket
file_content = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=S3_BUCKET,
                                    Key=email_key)

# get .eml file contents 
email_content = email.message_from_bytes(file_content["Body"].read())
print(email_content)
```

Nothing prints out and my lambda function times out. What should I do here? I want to be able to see the email contents somehow.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas:

```py
pd.read_csv(
    <botocore.response.StreamingBody object at 0x000001D64812BF70>
)
```

Comment: why would you use `pandas.read_csv`?

Comment: in order to read the boto3 response

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. Why do you think that `read_csv` will work with the response?